# Swapping divs at certain browser width

Tags: jquery

I have a small snippet of code I have been working on to swap two divs around when the browser width drops below 768, my issue with what I have is it works but only when you resize the window, not when it loads below 768, also when you expand the window back full screen it doesn't swap the divs back, any help would be appreciated. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/q8mctsds/)

```
    $(window).on('resize', function (event) {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth > 768) {
            jQuery(".swap2").after(jQuery(".swap1"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic of deciding when to swap into a function, say `swap()`. You can execute the function at runtime, and then again within the window resize event :)

```
// Declare the swap() function with accompanying logic
var swap = function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(".swap2").after($(".swap1"));
    }
}

// Swap on load
swap();

// Swap on resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
   swap();
});
```

However, this swapping action is **only unidirectional**. If you want a truly responsive one, you will have to swap the other direction with the `else` statement:

```
var swap = function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(".swap2").after($(".swap1"));
    } else {
        $(".swap2").before($(".swap1"));
    }
}
```

See fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/tpu1fg5y/

---

Alternatively, you can use a JS-free solution that uses the CSS3 flexbox `order` property:

```
.swap-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.swap1 { width:80%; background:red; order: 2; }
.swap2 { width:20%; background:blue; order: 1;}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .swap1 { order: 1; }
    .swap2 { order: 2; }
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8o91ohn6/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, that worked great but do you know how I can get them to swap back when you resize the window greater than 768. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Im guessing using "else" on the 1st function?

Comment: See updated answer :) I just realized that bi-directional swapping might be what you want.

Comment: If you are only supporting newer browsers in mind, you should consider using CSS flexbox :)

Comment: Thats spot on! Thank you!